# iOS/Swift UILocalizedIndexedCollation method section for collationStringSelector doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I have some problem with invoking method section for `collationStringSelector`. It doesn't find selector which I have properly defined.

Here is my method call:

```
for element in elements {
    if let indexable = element as? CollationIndexable {
        let collationIndex = collation.section(for: indexable, collationStringSelector: "collationString")

        if contentCollationIndexed[collationIndex] == nil {
            contentCollationIndexed[collationIndex] = [Element]()
        }
        contentCollationIndexed[collationIndex]!.append(element)
    }
}
```

Here is my protocol that Element type should implement

```
@objc protocol CollationIndexable : class {
    @objc var collationString : String { get }
}
```

And here is concrete Element type implementing protocol and selector property

```
extension Contact : CollationIndexable {

    @objc var collationString : String {
        return lastName
    }
}
```

UPDATE!

Ok, I have solved the problem,  Contact class MUST inherit form

> NSObject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used your example to make [this tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/) work with Swift 4.

```
var objects: [CollationIndexable] = [] {
        didSet {
            sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)
            let selector = #selector(getter: CollationIndexable.collationString)

            let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArray(from: objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object as AnyObject)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Here is my protocol that Element type should implement

```
@objc protocol CollationIndexable {
    @objc var collationString : String { get }
}
```

And here is concrete Element type implementing protocol and selector property

```
extension Contact : CollationIndexable {

    @objc var collationString : String {
        return lastName
    }
}
```